# Eggs smell "fishy"

Tags: eggs, fish, smell

I recently went to the supermarket and bought a carton of eggs and some fish (for dinner). I left both right next to each other in the fridge for a little over a day.

So I made myself some scrambled eggs with a tiny bit of pepper and milk in the morning and when I ate them I swear they smelled fishy, pun intended. I only used a few eggs and I don't want to waste the rest that I still have not used.

Is there anyway to remove the fishy smell that the eggs took in while in the fridge?

Comment: I'd say your best bet to not have them go to waste is to cook  a dish with fish and eggs in it. For use in regular egg dishes they are most likely ruined.

Answer (score 2):

Eggshells are porous, therefore the egg inside can absorb flavors. Once they absorb a flavor it tends to stay. If it's just an odor they are safe to eat.

Baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) is often used to neutralize odors in the fridge, you could try putting the eggs in a container with a big spoon of soda in it (not touching the eggs) for a couple of days. This **may** decrease the fishy smell in the eggs although I wouldn't bank on it. Your best bet is to use the eggs in a recipe with strong flavors and smells which will overpower any fishy odors.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is French and Italian folks who store eggs with truffles.  The eggs tend to pick up the truffle aroma.  Could it be that your eggs picked up the fish aroma?  Perhaps...I don't think  you can get rid of the smell...but, lesson learned.  Keep the eggs apart from other aromatic ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

To check if eggs are fresh, put them in a bowl of water, those that float will have a build up of gas in them, the source of much sulphurous fishy stink, throw out the ones that rise to the surface. Both eggs and milk will absorb strong flavours from items that are nearby.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause is but I know not everyone can smell or taste this. I cracked an egg once and the smell was instant and pretty strong, I had a friend smell it and he couldn't smell anything. I've experienced this with both regular and organic eggs but it seems to happen a lot less often with organic eggs. Also, I don't know if these things are related but I seem to find bitter things more bitter than most people. I think it's why I don't like alcohol especially beer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the eggs with something that would be more potent of a taste than the fish flavor in the eggs. Maybe use salsa and cheese. You might even scramble the eggs and use that in a different dish.

The eggs, along with many other foods with allow for chemicals to transfer through to them. Smell is simply little bits of matter floating around in the air.

Your eggs actually already have fish in them. As GdD said, you might as well put more fish in them, or add flavors to the eggs that you would add to the type of fish you have next to it.